# Multi-role PowerApps Application, Dataverse Data Source

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, dataverse

I am building HR App in Power Apps. I have a Dataverse Table with columns "Employee", and "Salary". I need every Employee to see only their salary in PowerApps, which is accomplished with filters, but since I am sharing application, I have to Share the datasource as well. How do I avoid employees being able to see each others salary in Dataverse Table? Is there a way for them to have access to Dataverse table only through PowerApps without having access to the actual table? Is there any workarounds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prerequisites: table Employee must be business owned. Assign users a security role giving them only read privileges to table Employee for records they own.

Then you have two options:

1. Assign only the Employee record to a user that holds her/his personal data.

Or:

2. Keep ownership on the HR level and share the proper Employee record with the user.